# Can't get JUnit tests to fail in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm trying out Android development, but haven't come too far because I'm unable to get a test case to fail.

I have the following test case in the androidTest folder:

```
package com.example.aaronf.myapplication;

import android.test.*;

public class ToDoListTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    private void newToDoListHasNoItems() {
        assertEquals(new ToDoList().length, 0);
    }

    private void addingToDoGivesLengthOfOne() {
        ToDoList toDoList = new ToDoList();
        toDoList.add(new ToDo());
        assertEquals(toDoList.length, 1);
    }

    public void runTests() {
        newToDoListHasNoItems();
        addingToDoGivesLengthOfOne();
    }

    public ToDoListTest() {
        super();
        runTests();
    }
}
```

The `ToDoList` class looks like:

```
package com.example.aaronf.myapplication;

public class ToDoList {
    public int length = 0;

    public void add(ToDo toDo) {

    }
}
```

It seems like it should fail on addingToDoGivesLengthOfOne(), but I get a green bar.

**EDIT**

I should add that adding @Test annotations to the methods generates a symbol not found error.

**EDIT**

I visited the suggested post [My Junit test doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493808). However, there is a difference with my problem. My methods used to have the test prefix, but this didn't affect the outcome. Also, the @Test annotation, as I mentioned before, is flagged with an error: "Cannot resolve symbol Test".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Junit test doesn't run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493808/my-junit-test-doesnt-run)

Comment: yes, you forgot about `@Test` annotation. Please start using logs to check the values.You may always create test with one method, which would be 'fail();' - you kknow what it cause

Comment: As I mentioned, the @Test symbol isn't recognized as a symbol. Also, I just tried appending the word test to the beginning of each test method and made them public. Still nothing.
I also clicked on the test class and ran it specifically. That yielded the same result. BTW, the number of tests listed as running corresponds to the number of classes in the tests folder. Once again, I'm using Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my Test Artifact was set to Android Instrumentation Tests instead of Unit Tests. Since my unit tests were being added to the Android Instrumentation group, the unit testing stuff wasn't being recognized.